# How to launch installed application automatically when android TV leanback is switched ON?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot, android-tv, leanback

Im trying my application to launch automatically, when TV is switched ON. Its not working.

```
    public class PlugInControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.d("Intent Action",action);
    }
}
```

In Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".PlugInControlReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Its not working in TV. Is there any way or any different solution for TV framework. I have searched a lot wouldn't find the solution.

Comment: Using an android version above Android 8.0 by any chance?

Comment: I have tried with Android 7.0. Need to check with with above 8.0. Its possible to check with TV emulators?

Comment: I suppose It's possible but surely less reliable. I'd suggest using an android tv streamer.